# Convert CLLocation to CLLocationDegrees

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

How can I convert CLLocation to CLLocationDegrees, so that I could create CLLocationCoordinate2D structure?

Comment: is it CLLocation or CLLovation?

Answer (score 6):

Just get the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` directly from the `coordinate` property of CLLocation.

```
myLocationCoordinate2D = myLocation.coordinate;
```

[Reference Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126)

Answer (score 3):

CLLocation.coordinate property will return CLLocationCoordinate2D for you. No need to do any conversions.